# How to change string in a list of strings into into an integer, perform a calculation on it and then make it a list of strings again

Tags: python

I would need to change string into an integer  to perform calculation (divide it by 2  to get
a result of 500) and then make it a list of strings again.. eg. `['ALT', '500', 'ASM']`
I keep getting

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

```
mail = ['ALT', '1000', 'ASM']
print((mail[1]) / 2)
```

Comment: When you put that error into a search engine, did anything come up?

Comment: You need to cast the string into an int. Use this: int(mail[1]) / 2

Comment: You are trying to do division on a string. you need to convert it to `int` before you divide. Use `print (int(mail[1])/2)`

Comment: Thank you so much, I did try google, tried the search here, looked also into a textbook, stupid me, I am ashamed to say I spent the whole afternoon trying to figure it out  :-)

Answer (score 1):

To perform your requested operation you simply have to convert the string. Python, like any programming language I know of, doesn't allow math operations directly on strings. The process of changing the type of an object, in your case from a String to an Integer, is called casting. To solve your issue you want to change your second line to this:

```
print(int(mail[1]) / 2)
```

The element `'1000'` is being changed from a string to an integer and afterwards the calculation is performed.

If you want to store the result as a string again you could use something like this:

```
a = int(mail[1]) / 2 # convert to integer and perform math
a = str(a) # Change integer back to string

mail[1] = a # Assign the value to the list again
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfect explanation, that is exactly what I needed, now I also know how to use it back in the list of strings......

Comment: @JanT glad I could help. Maybe consider making this the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(mail[1])
print(a/2)
500
```